# What is the minimum xcode version required to build cordova ios 4.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I just installed Xcode 7.2.1 today not latest version latest is 7.3. I am able to build default ios version but when i try to build cordova ios version 4.0 it gives following error.

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainViewController.o app/Classes/MainViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Applications/apps/band/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,app.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,app,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Applications/apps/band/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Applications/apps/band/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Applications/apps/band/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Applications/apps/band/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5
```

My current version of cordova is 5.3.1. with latest version of Ionic. So my concern is is this error due to older version of xcode or some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per official cordova [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/ios/), the Xcode 4.5 is the minimum compatible version for cordova ios 4.0.0 version. So in your case, Xcode version shouldn't be an issue. It could be some permission issue. Try updating cordova and remove ios platform and trying adding it again and rebuild. Hope it helps